# storing a double type value from html textbox into a c# variable

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know that how to store a double type value from html textbox into a c# variable?
I have a html textbox with Id txtCost and that will hold a double value.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What stopping you from storing this?

Comment: `double.Parse(txtCost.Text)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the value using `double.Parse()` like so:

```
var value = double.Parse(txtCost.Text);
```

Although parsing numerical values has some globalization caveats (like how it parses dots and commas). You can read more about the parse method at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't even need to do that... Just make use of the Model Binder built into ASP.NET. Using MVC, I parse a `ViewModel` and that `ViewModel` has a `public double SomeNumber {get;set;}` which populates a textbox, the Model Binder automatically type casts it...

Comment: if i am passing a value than its fine but, as i am leaving it empty compiler is showing me an error that, "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @user2512996 Yeah, the `double.Parse()` method does not accept empty strings, so you need to check for that first

Comment: @No1_Melman That sounds really interesting! I assumed Web Forms was used here, and I have never used the Model Binder in a Web Forms app. I'll definitively look into that! :)

Comment: @pcm2 I highly advise looking into use `ASP.NET MVC` it makes using `Models` and passing data very easy. Also makes building the `View` a breeze. [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/)

Comment: yes, i am using webforms, but what is the solution for that?? please tell

Comment: @No1_Melman Yes! I prefer MVC over Web Forms any day! But the unfortunate truth is that a lot of apps out there are Web Forms. :/

Comment: @user2512996 Starting with ASP.NET 4.5 (I think), MVC-like model binding is available through the use of Strongly typed data controls. I found an excellent blog post about it: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/04/02/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-model-binding.aspx

Comment: @pcm2 just because a lot of those apps are Web Forms, doesn't mean you can't start using it... how do you implement new things if everyone kept going, "well... there are a lot of the original stuff out there... whats the point" ... there would be no innovation if that happened :P

Comment: i can't even use .text its working with .value as it is html text box, but still it is not accepting empty string, if anybody know than please suggest me some good solution for that, or should i use asp textbox rather then html?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you use, if it's an asp:textbox you get its value by the Text property, and if it's a HTMLInputControl you get its value by the Value property. The fact remains that the Parse method does not accept an empty string. Ergo is your textbox is empty, you will get the error

Answer (score 0):

```
Double val=Convert.ToDouble(txtCost.Text);
```